# Status bar to display a cell value?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I use the status bar in nearly all my macros . If implemented correctly , allows you to see where your code is at.

E.g

```
SysCmd(4, "Sorting...")

SysCmd(5)’Set status bar back to normal
```

Question - How do I get the status bar to display a cell value?

E.g

```
SysCmd(4, "Sorting...") & xl.("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

Above doesn’t work, but is there a way of doing this, in Access VBA ?

Comment: What kind of object is `xl` The way to refer to a range in excel from Excel would be `[Worksheet Object].Range("A1")`  If you want to use "Sheet1" then you have to reference a workbook object in front of that.  And from Access you need a Excel Application object in front of that.

Comment: I named xl as my Excel Application object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use 4 (`acSysCmdSetStatus`) as the first argument to `SysCmd`, you can include only one additional argument ... so two arguments total, not three.

But you can combine your proposed second and third arguments into one string, and `SysCmd` will cooperate ...

```vb
SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, "Sorting... " & xl.("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

Note I assumed `xl` in your cell reference, `xl.("Sheet1").Range("A1")`, is an Excel workbook object.  Since it turns out `xl` is an application object, Sobigen's suggestion, `xl.activeworkbook.sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`, makes sense to me.

But whatever the correct cell reference is, take that and concatenate it with whatever else you want to appear in the status text ... and use that entire string as the second argument to `SysCmd`

Comment: I think you'll get a syntax error as it is.  If xl is an application object then changing `xl.("Sheet1").Range("A1")` to `xl.activeworkbook.sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")` should fix it.